# Python OOP output return is wrong, someone has an idea?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning how to write object oriented programming in python and I have this code I wrote (well part of it, some of it is part of the class I'm following)

```
class Toolbox:
    def __init__(self, tool):
        pass
    
class Hammer:
    def __init__(self, color):
        pass

class Screwdriver:
    def __init__(self, size):
        pass

class Screw:
    MAX_TIGHTNESS = 5
    def __init__(self):
        self.tightness = 0
    def loosen(self):
        if (self.tightness > 0):
            self.tightness -= 1
    def tighten(self):
        if (self.tightness < self.MAX_TIGHTNESS):
            self.tightness += 1
    def __str__(self):
        return "Screw with tightness {}".format(self.tightness)

class Nail:
    def __init__(self):
        self.in_wall = False
    def nail_in(self):
        if (not self.in_wall):
            self.in_wall = True
    def remove(self):
        if (self.in_wall):
            self.in_wall = False
    def __str__(self):
        return "Nail {}in wall.".format("" if self.in_wall else "not ")


hammer = Hammer("blue")
sdriver = Screwdriver("300")
#tbox = Toolbox()
tool1 = Toolbox(hammer)
tool2 = Toolbox(sdriver)
screw1 = Screw()
print(screw1)
screw1.tighten()
print(screw1)
nail1 = Nail()
print(nail1)
nail1.nail_in
print(nail1)
```

The output of print(screw1) works but print(nail1) gives me the same output (Nail in wall.) twice instead Nail in wall. I guess there's a problem in my logic and I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone help me?

Thanks!
Marc

Comment: You need to **call** `nail_in`.  So do `nail1.nail_in()`. Note the brackets.

Comment: @ma.girard12  I was wondering if you are kind enough to share the source of this example. You didn't define` in_wall` but you used directly in `class Nail`. What are your methods & instances in this OOP exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **call** `nail_in` - just as you are already doing with `screw1.tighten`.  So do this (note the brackets here):

```
nail1.nail_in()
```

With this fix, your code works:

```
Screw with tightness 0
Screw with tightness 1
Nail not in wall.
Nail in wall.
```

By referring to the function but without the brackets, it is a syntactically valid line of code, but it is just an expression for the function object itself, and as you are not doing anything with it (such as assigning it to a variable), it is then simply discarded.

Comment: Thank you! I knew the problem was right before my eyes!!